# Populatin HTML table using PHP and Database Values

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to correctly display the records of my table. The problem that I am currently having is that I am repeating records.

I am using a foreach and a for loop to populate the table. The problem comes in when I use a 2nd foreach to access my 2d array in order to grab its values and compare them. The records repeat as many times as there are arrays in the 2d array. I don't know exactly where to place my foreach or if I should use it in this case.

There should only be 1 button in for each row/column combination like a normal table

[image: Here is my problem]

Here is the code

```
<table style="float: left;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
      <th>
        <?php echo $dateArray[$i]; ?>
      </th>
    <?php endfor ?>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data['timeData'] as $timeTable): ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
          <td>
            <?php foreach ($data['scheduleData'] as $scheduleData): ?> The problem lies here
              <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <?php if (($scheduleData['time_id'] == $timeTable['time_id'] && $scheduleData['date'] == $dateArray[$i] && $scheduleData['status'] === '1')) { ?>
                  <label class="btn btn-success">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $timeTable['time_id']; ?>"
                           name="time[]" value="<?= $timeTable['time_id']; ?> "
                           autocomplete="off"><?= $timeTable['time_hour']; ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" hidden id="<?= $dateArray[$i]; ?>"
                           name="date[]" value="<?= $dateArray[$i]; ?>">
                  </label>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $timeTable['time_id']; ?>"
                           name="time[]" value="<?= $timeTable['time_id']; ?> "
                           autocomplete="off"><?= $timeTable['time_hour']; ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" hidden id="<?= $dateArray[$i]; ?>"
                           name="date[]" value="<?= $dateArray[$i]; ?>">
                  </label>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
          </td>
        <?php endfor ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what the `$data['scheduleData']` contains:

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [person_id] => 8 
                      [time_id] => 1 
                      [date] => 2017-05-08 
                      [status] => 1 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [person_id] => 8 
                      [time_id] => 2 
                      [date] => 2017-05-09 
                      [status] => 1 ))
```

My `$data['timeData']` contains:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [time_id] => 1 [time_hour] => 00:00:00 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [time_id] => 2 [time_hour] => 01:00:00 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [time_id] => 3 [time_hour] => 02:00:00 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [time_id] => 4 [time_hour] => 03:00:00 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [time_id] => 5 [time_hour] => 04:00:00 ) 
         .     ....       ....              ....        ....
       [23] => Array ( [time_id] => 24 [time_hour] => 23:00:00 ) )
```

My $dateArray

```
$dateArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $dateArray[$i] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$i day", strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))));
}
```

Comment: do one thing share input arrays which you have and expected output you want so that we can help you out.

Comment: So you want me to give you my current output and my desired output?

Comment: I mean to say just share those arrays on which you are iterating and you expected out from these array,

Comment: Could you give me an example ? I still don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: That really dosen't do much. The problem lies using the foreach(($data['scheduleData']) loop

Comment: i got the issue... i am posting an answer check that one..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143645/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-viteazul).

Comment: The problem was there where you pointed `The problem lies here` check my post and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your for loop is the issue (within both foreach loops), why i actually you need the loop there. If you want to limit the records do it using your query. If you use the for loop there, it will repeat the records...

Did you try removing it? Mostly it might cause the issue...

EDIT:
Change this code :
.

```
   <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
          <td>
            <?php foreach ($data['scheduleData'] as $scheduleData): ?> The problem lies here
              <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

to

```
   <?php foreach ($data['scheduleData'] as $scheduleData): ?> 
          <td>                
              <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

And properly close the tags, and remove the closing for `for loop`

Comment: I need that for loop to populate the table. My table is basically a 2d array

Comment: I get the idea, but you already looping, so you don't need another loop to do it. What actually your do is loop that foreach for 7 times...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying I should loop my 2nd foreach only 7 times?

Comment: Nope, what i am saying is, the for loop your are using will run the foreach loop 7 times...

Comment: Well thats the thing, I don't know where to place it to make it work. I tried before the 1st foreach and after the 1st foreach. Both just double the amount of rows my table has.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try whether it works for you

Comment: Sorry for your hardwork but it dosen't work. I need that for loop to populate my table. In combination with the foreach ($data['timeData'] as $timeTable), the $dateArray is used to insert time values row by row

Comment: Continue this in the chat